# How to build a Multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a multidimensional array in PHP using an array of string that I am cutting up so the string of 1:wlrb@yahoo.com:7:8.35 becomes

```
"id": "1",  
"email_address": "wlrb@yahoo.com",  
"domain": "yahoo.com",  
"number_of_orders": "7",    
"total_order_value": "£8.35"
```

In JavaScript I would create an object containing the above values and put it into an array but what is the equivalent in PHP?
So far I have the below code which gives me

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [email] => wlrb@yahoo.com
>   [domain] => yahoo.com [number_of_orders] => 7 [total_order_value] =>
>   8.35 )

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('orderdata');
/* echo $data; */

$lines = explode("\n", $data);

array_splice($lines, 0, 8);
/* var_dump($lines); */

array_splice($lines, -3);
/* var_dump($lines); */

/* removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero) values */
$lines = array_values(array_filter($lines, 'strlen'));


function arraySort($lines ,$i) {
    $rep = new stdClass();
    $rep->id = strId($lines, $i);
    $rep->email = strEmail($lines, $i);
    $rep->domain = strDomain($lines, $i);
    $rep->number_of_orders = orderNo($lines, $i);
    $rep->total_order_value = orderValue($lines, $i);
    /* var_dump($rep); */
    return $rep;
}


function strDomain($lines, $i) {
    if($lines[$i] == null){
        return "";
    } 
    else {
        $str = $lines[$i];
        $splt = explode(':', $str);
        $domain = explode('@', $splt[1]);
        return $domain[1];
    }
}


function strId($lines, $i) {
    if($lines[$i] == null){
        return "";
    } 
    else {
        $str = $lines[$i];
        $splt = explode(':', $str);
        return $splt[0];
    }

}


function strEmail($lines, $i) {
    if($lines[$i] == null){
        return "";
    } 
    else {
        $str = $lines[$i];
        $splt = explode(':', $str);
        return $splt[1];
    }
}


function orderNo($lines, $i) {
    if($lines[$i] == null){
        return "";
    } 
    else {
        $str = $lines[$i];
        $splt = explode(':', $str);
        return $splt[2];
    }
}


function orderValue($lines, $i) {
    if($lines[$i] == null){
        return "";
    } 
    else {
        $str = $lines[$i];
        $splt = explode(':', $str);
        return '£' + $splt[3];
    }
}

$reports = array();
$reps = array();
for($i = 0, $length = count($lines); $i < $length; ++$i) {
    $reps = arraySort($lines, $i);
    array_push($reports, $reps);
}

?>
```

but when I try to search the array with

```
$filteredArray = 
array_filter($reports, function($element) use($search){
  return isset($element['domain']) && $element['domain'] == $search;
});
```

I get the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as
>   array in phpData.php:110 Stack trace: #0
>   [internal function]: {closure}(Object(stdClass)) #1
>   phpData.php(111): array_filter(Array,
>   Object(Closure)) #2 {main} thrown in
>   phpData.php on line 110

Is this because of the use of `$rep = new stdClass();`in my arraySort function? If so what should I be using?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason, you are trying to use an object as array, which is only possible if you pass the object to `\ArrayObject`(http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) or just use an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and shortest solution would be :

```
$value = "1:wlrb@yahoo.com:7:8.35";
$keys = array('id', 'email_address', 'number_of_orders', 'total_order_value');
$fused = array_combine($keys, explode(':', $value));
$fused['domain'] = strDomain($fused['email_address']); //using your "strDomain()" function
```

It will give you the array you want, except you won't have the `£` sign in your order value.

Comment: Thanks this is a great solution that saves a lot of code.  How could I also retrieve the domain which explodes @ giving yahoo.com?

Comment: I think maybe like this                                                                                   $value = strDomain($lines, $i);
$fused["domain"] = "$value";

Comment: See the updated answer, I think it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use object obtention method like this:

```
$filteredArray = 
array_filter($reports, function($element) use($search){
  return isset($element->domain) && $element->domain == $search;
});
```